# How to do Onclick Button show and Hide in foreach case using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using a accordion for closing and opening content when clicked.

It has a bar section which, when clicked, content below will show like on this example : http://jeevanscientific.com/resources.html

I need to add a up button/downbutton on rightside of each bar.
Once clicked on particular bar only that bar shows down button. It is like hiding and showing down and up button with respect to button click.

The problem is that I am using a foreach to display items. How can I implement this scenario ?

Here is my HTML :

```
foreach (var i in footerPage.StaticPagePersons)
{
    <H1>@Html.Raw(@i.Type) </H1>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading datalist" id="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@i.Id">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down table-middle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up table-middle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h1 class="accordion-toggle table-middle">
                    @Html.Raw(@i.Name)
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="@i.Id" class="accordion-body collapse out">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <img ng-src="@i.ImagePath" alt="logo" class="img-thumbnail img-wrap content-image" />
                    <h1>@Html.Raw(@i.Name)</h1>
                    <h3>@Html.Raw(@i.Title)</h3>
                    <br />
                    @Html.Raw(@i.BioDetail)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

#### [Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882237/#comment-63267601)

right side of each tab.. that's requirement... when clicked should show up button, else down button

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you create a set of accordions with the same `id="accordion2"`? Does each accordion contain only one panel? Can you show the HTML-code that you get as a result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
foreach (var i in person.Persons)
{
    <H1>@Html.Raw(@i.Type) </H1>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading datalist" id="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@i.Id">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down table-middle" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <h1 class="accordion-toggle table-middle">
                    @Html.Raw(@i.Name)
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="@i.Id" class="accordion-body collapse out">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <img ng-src="@i.ImagePath" alt="logo" class="img-thumbnail img-wrap content-image" />
                    <h1>@Html.Raw(@i.Name)</h1>
                    <h3>@Html.Raw(@i.Title)</h3>
                    <br />
                    if(your condition){
                        @Html.Raw(@i.BioDetail) //it will show only if your ncondtion satisfied
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
        });

        $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How does your solution help to change the button depending on the status of the tab?

Comment: You [have changed the essence of your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37997863/revisions) after I made my comment. Up to this point you just have advised to use the `if` condition. This condition acts at the stage of creating the page. Therefore, it does not help to toggle the button after the page loads. So your old answer did not solve this issue. In this situation, the terse answer to my comment looks unpleasant.

Comment: I think she might have meant she has corrected the code to explain how it worked as per your question in the comment above, maybe.

Comment: she asked me to do something else, for the actual question i  updated the code.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with pure css, if the link above shows a working example.

What you would need is:

```
.accordion-heading .fa {
  display: none;
  //Other css required for the fa display in general can go here.
}

.AccordionPanelOpen .fa-chevron-up {
  display: block;
}

.AccordionPanelClosed .fa-chevron-down {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The current answer does not really answer your question, I follow the answer of @Arathi, this is done via CSS, when the bootstrap accordion is collapsed or not, it will have an addition class. the `<div class="accordion-heading datalist" id="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#@i.Id">` rule will switch between `.collapsed` class and off. So When this div has the `collapsed` class you want to show `.fa-chevron-down` else you want to show `.fa-chevron-up`. You can manage this by the following code:

```
.accordion-header .fa-chevron-down {
  display: block;
}
.accordion-header .fa-chevron-up {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-header.collapsed .fa-chevron-up {
  display: block;
}
.accordion-header.collapsed .fa-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}
```

Now when the `.accordion-header` will have the `collapsed` class the up chevron will show and the down chevron will hide. If you want to add transition or something like that you could also use `opacity` 0 - 1. Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 4):

I have a CSS-solution for your issue. And I've noticed several problems in your code.

### 1) Several problems

1. Your current code creates a set of accordions with the same `id="accordion2"`. It's wrong. The `id` must be unique.
2. Each accordion contains only one panel. This is strange. Accordions have been invented to manage multiple panels.
3. You've replaced Bootstrap classes. For example, your code uses `.accordion-group` and `.accordion-heading` instead of `.panel-group` and `.panel-heading`. I need to see your code in order to understand what are the differences between them.

### 2) How to toggle icons using CSS

Let's start with the standard [Accordion example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion).

You can add FontAwesome icons as a content of [the `:after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```
.panel-title > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

Bootstrap uses [the `aria-expanded` attribute](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-collapse-accessibility) for the control element.

> The plugin will automatically toggle this attribute based on whether or not the collapsible element has been opened or closed.

So you can toggle icons by CSS:

```
.panel-title > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

Please check the demo. Is it what you want to achieve?
https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/1wx4ubvc/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-title > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.panel-title > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="panel-body">
          Text 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
          Item 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
          Item 3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

### 3) Try this code

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

foreach (var i in footerPage.StaticPagePersons)
{
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-@i.Id">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-@i.Id" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-@i.Id">
          @Html.Raw(@i.Type)
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-@i.Id" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-@i.Id">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <img ng-src="@i.ImagePath" alt="logo" class="img-thumbnail img-wrap content-image" />
        <h1>@Html.Raw(@i.Name)</h1>
        <h3>@Html.Raw(@i.Title)</h3>
        <br />
        @Html.Raw(@i.BioDetail)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}

</div>
```

And use this CSS:

```
.panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-title > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.panel-title > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this code jquery :


    $('.accordion-group h1').click(function(){

    $(this).parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-body').slideToggle();

    });


buttons should be like this
<ul>
  <li>button1</li>
  <li>button2</li>
  <li>button3</li>
</ul>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').click(function(){
  var pos =  $( "li" ).index(this);
   $('panel-group panel-body:nth-child('+pos+')').slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: what i need is toggling of button. everything is working fine. button up and down need to be added by me

Comment: As per your requirement http://jeevanscientific.com/ i was given . Button means ? where is it ?

Comment: right side of each tab.. thats requiremnt... when clicked should show upbutton, else down button

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

jquery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)  Display(if the element is hidden) or hide(if the element is displayed) the matched elements. so here when you click on the  tag we toggle(show/hide) the element after it that(the **glyphicon**).

```js
      $('.panel-heading a').click(function(){
        $(this).next('span.glyphicon').toggle();
      })
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;"></span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: $(this).next('span.glyphicon').toggle(); why this code is using for? can u expalin?

Comment: in your case no up button is there